# eBay Fulfillment API : cannot retrieve orders

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to retrieve all the orders for my test user (seller) via the sandbox api explorer.
I created and published an offer with my seller user, then bought it with my buyer user.
Using the old Trading API and the GetSellerTransactions method I can see that the item has been purchased.
I am then trying to use the CompleteSale method of the Trading API, specifing the itemId and transactionId of the bought product.
But I am still unable to see the order, not with the Fulfillment API method getOrders nor getOrder (specifying the order id).

When I check the status of the payment using the Trading API, it is 'incomplete'.
So I updated my 'payment policy' with the property : "immediatePayment" : "true". But doing so I can no longer buy a product with my buyer user as I get an error.

If anyone knows how I can retrive orders using restAPI in the sandbox, or buy a product with immediate payment, that would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Listings created with Trading APIs require to be migrated to be visible with new fulfillment APIs.
Search for migration API

Comment: this is not true

Answer (score 0):

Fulfillment API, as name suggest is only for completed order that needs to be fulfilled. Here is a note on their page.

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/overview.html

Note: The Fulfillment API covers only the transactions that have completed the checkout process. This API does not cover pending payment purchases that require upfront payment before shipment.

Try marking your order as `Paid` via UI or via `CompleteSale` api - https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/CompleteSale.html